# Fastest way to convert boost::optional to std::optional

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I need to use boost libraries in my project, such as boost::property_tree and boost::convert, which in turn use boost::optional. At the same time, the interface I'm implementing uses std::optional. What is the fastest way to convert boost::optional to std::optional?

There is my suggestion

```
template<class T>
inline std::optional<T> ToStd(boost::optional<T>&& opt) {
  if (opt) {
    return std::move(opt.value());
  } else {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
}
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: This is ok with one main drawback: you can only give rvalues. You need to deduce the whole type to use perfect-forwarding and handle all cv-qualified optional types.

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests if you can) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: @Rerito see my comment that I'll move to your answer

Comment: I think it should be: `return std::move(opt).value();` since there is [T&& optional<T>::value() && ;](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics___optional_values.html#reference_optional_value_move).

Answer (score 2):

Since one would most likely want to be able to pass this `ToStd` entity to a higher-order function, such as an STL algorithm, e.g.

```cpp
std::transform(someBoostOpts.begin(),
               someBoostOpts.end(),
               resultingStdOpts.begin(),
               ToStd);
```

it would be better to make it a function object, so that its name is not shared across multiple instatiations/overloads. (If you try the above snippet with your `ToStd`, you'll see a compilation failure along the lines of "I don't know which templ.instantiation/overload you are referring to".)

To do so, the most practical way is to write it as a lambda:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto BoostOptToStdOpt = [](auto&& opt) {
  if (opt.has_value()) {
    return std::make_optional(std::forward<decltype(opt)>(opt).value());
  } else {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
};
```

The `.has_value()` and `.value()` will cause a compilation failure if you try to use it with something that doesn't have those member functions (but it will also "work", i.e. doing a usless job, if you pass to it a `std::optional`).

If you really want a nice error if you pass to it a non-`boost::optional`, then you can write a type trait and `static_assert`.

---

As regards the question of whethere there's a faster way, I wouldn't expect one exists, for a simple reason: `std::optional` and `boost::optional` occupy precisely the same place in C++, the latter being the older, experimental solution, and the latter the standardised version that supersedes it.

It's not like, say, having such a handy way to convert a `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` (i.e. you can `std::shared_ptr<T> s = some_unique_ptr_to_T;`); such a construtor exists because the two types fulfill different necessities, *and* it is  semantically sensible to transform a `std::unique_ptr` into a `std::shared_ptr` (and to explicitly forbid the inverse conversion).
i
`std::optional` and `boost::optional` have the same identical semantics (at least in the intentions), and providing a standard way to move from one to another would even fool you into thinking that they fulfill different needs, but that would be untrue.

Ideally, you'd want every program to be renewed and to stop using `boost::optional` in favour of `std::optional`.

Comment: Ah yes very nice statement about making it a function object. On top of what you said it also makes sure that using that object, you cannot have ADL messing up the call and this makes it really good to add mandatory static checks!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the right way to go, except it only handles rvalues.
You need to deduce the type completely in order to handle all value categories (possibly cv-qualified).

With that in mind, some traits might be useful:

```
template< typename >
struct optional_traits : std::false_type {};

template< typename T >
struct optional_traits< boost::optional< T > >: std::true_type {
    using value_type = T;
    using type = boost::optional< T >;
};
```

Now you can restrict your helper using SFINAE (with C++20 it would be even cleaner thanks to an appropriate concept)

```
template< typename T, std::enable_if_t< optional_traits< std::remove_cvref_t< T > >::value >* = nullptr >
auto toStd(T&& opt)
{
    using ValueType = typename optional_traits< std::remove_cvref_t< T > >::value_type;

    // When the given boost::optional uses a reference type, trigger an error.
    // Do not try to convert boost::optional< T& > to std::optional< T >.
    static_assert(
        !std::is_reference_v< ValueType >,
        "Reference types are not supported for std::optional");
    using StdOptType = std::optional< ValueType >;

    if (opt)
        return StdOptType{ std::forward< T >(opt).value() };
    
    return StdOptType{};
}
```

Comment: keep in mind though that the semantics are very trickily different. I'd  recommend NO reference semantics, just to avoid confusion (`boost::optional<T&>` works, `std::optional<T&>` doesn't). In any case, you need to ensure the cases where the semantics are different don't compile.

Comment: @sehe I was not aware of that. I edited the answer accordingly (just a static_assert to make sure we fail to compile when given `boost::optional< T&(&) >`